# Easiest way to set up SQL Database for local testing of C# project in Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2013

Okay, so this is going to sound stupid or trivial, but please, humor me.  I am writing a personal project in C# using Visual Studio 2013 Express and some of the code is going to hit a SQL database.  Before I hit other databases, I want to test it locally and make sure that it performs as expected.  However, I can't seem to find any tutorial that either is complete or works in order to get a SQL database up from nothing.

First, I tried installing SqlLocalDb 2014.  Even after the tools I can't figure out where there is a UI that I can type in scripts to create a database.

I tried the directions here: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-SQL-Server-Database
But at step 3, the option to create a database is greyed out, and searching that issue got me nowhere.

I've tried adding a new SQL Server Database Project to my solution.  This looked like it would work exactly, but when I designed the table I couldn't figure out how to actually deploy/publish it so I could connect to it.  I get a SQL file, and I can't figure out what to do with it from there.  I found instructions on how to publish it, but it seemed the only directions were to publish to a remote server (and I want to use a local one).

I tried the instructions here (yes, I know they're for 2012): http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms233763(VS.110).aspx but I can't find the Server Explorer / Database Explorer.  I found the Server Explorer (where my table doesn't appear) and the SQl Server Object Explorer, where my table does appear but I can't figure out how to populate it with dummy data or how to connect to it.

This should not be this hard and I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What type of project (web, winforms, etc) and are you using entity framework or an ORM of any kind?

Comment: ASP.NET Web Application, and I am not using any entity framework / ORM .

Comment: For those wondering, I ended up going with MySQL.

I followed these 3 tutorials, in order:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-admin.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-creating-a-model.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/423233/How-to-Connect-to-MySQL-Using-Csharp

Answer (score 1):

Hitting F5 deploys your SQL Server Database to a localdb instance that you can connect your application to. You can [see the connection string](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/06/06/getting-started-with-localdb-debugging-using-ssdt.aspx) for this database by right-clicking on the project -> Properties -> Debug -> Target Connection String.

You can use this connection string in your application code to connect to the local database and test it - place it in a configuration file that can be replaced with the real database connection string in your production code. Alternatively use a database first [Entity Framework Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907) to connect your application to your database, and you can just change the App.Config file to specify whether to target your test or production database. That's a really nice way to handle this since it will produce all the code you need to work with the database.

Comment: Ha, I really wish you had posted that before I went through all that work to find another solution.  This sounds exactly like what I was hoping to find.  I'll have to try this and I'll give you answer credit then.

Answer (score 0):

You could use xampp. From there you can create local databases and then you could talk to the created database using "localhost" instead of the productive server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up going with another solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the record there is some information on **Accessing Data in Visual Studio** at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzabh8c4.aspx

And specifically to answer your question there is a "**Walkthrough: Creating a Local Database File in Visual Studio**" at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx